# IF EXIST Drop Table in View results in Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'. message

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The following code in my view products the error message  **Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'**

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[IDW_vwGetProductOutPut] 
AS  
IF EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects 
  WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempPackaging')) 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempPackaging 
END  . . . . . .     

--code to create temp table goes here . .  and so on
```

How do I code this please?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Are you saying that whenever anyone runs any query against the `IDW_vwGetProductOutPut` view, you want the `#TempPackaging` table to be dropped and recreated?? That is really not the purpose of a view.

Comment: you cannot use temp tables in View, use CTE or stored procedure or table funcitons

Comment: How do I use a CTE for this? The reason this is happening within a view is in order to get at the data from one of my stored procs, I am needing to first execute and load that data into a temptable which I then join to to get at the information in the result set from my main view.

Comment: create another SP that will call existing SP and stores data in table variable, then join this to other table and return data, call this new SP in your view

Comment: you can often remove a temporary table by refactoring your query.  If you show us how you populate #TempPackaging then we might be able to explore that for you.

Answer (score 6):

A [view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) can only contain SELECT statements, what you have is more like a [stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx).

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[IDW_spGetProductOutPut] 
AS  
IF EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects 
  WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TempPackaging')) 
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #TempPackaging 
END  . . . . . .     

--code to create temp table goes here . .  and so on
```

Comment: You can simplify your if to:

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempPackaging') IS NOT NULL
       BEGIN 
           .....
       END

Comment: @JTC - Yup, that's the way I'd go, but I was trying to stick to the OP's original code and not confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this functionality is available with SQL Server. As a workaround you may want to execute your logic in a stored procedure.